# How to count frequency of name-phrases from a Unicode text source, using Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I'm a newbie when coming to Python. So please help me on this. Basically I have a text novel files, usually around 100k-300k words. And the source text is Unicode utf8. I want to write a Python scripts that only find names and sort those names by frequency. But only display that name if the name appear more than or equal 2 times.

A name is usually made up of 2 - 4 words and is Tile-formatted.

Here is a paragraph example from a source text, bear with the language:

```
**A Lý Khuê Ân** tính toán rất rõ ràng. Lúc đầu muốn giết **Tát Lạc Mông**, hắn không có gì phải sợ. Dù sao **Tát Lạc Mông** cũng là tốn hao tài phú của **Bác Y** gia tộc và một nhân tình mới được Ngả Khẳng hỗ trợ. Cho thấy **Ngả Khẳng** khồng coi trọng. Nếu như **Ngả Khảng** không lấy tài phú ban cho **Tát Lạc Mông** một giọt Chủ thần lực, vậy mới gọi là coi trọng. “Giết **Tát Lạc Mông** không sao, nhưng giết **Bối Bối**, mặc dù tỷ lệ phát hiện không cao, nhưng bj phát hiện, ta hẳn phải chết không thể nghi ngờ” **A Lý Khuê Ân** khong hề muốn chọc vào **Bối Lỗ Đặc**.
```

expected results:

```
Tát Lạc Mông 4
A Lý Khuê Ân 2
Ngả Khẳng 2
Bối Lỗ Đặc 1 (don't show)
Bối Bối 1 (dont show)
```

Here is my code that I come up with, the Regex way return no result, and the sendcond one return 1 result which is "A Lý: 1"  :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import regex as re
import collections

file = open(("file-path-goes-here"), encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

# Try to do with Regex
regexObj = re.compile(r'[A-ZĐÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸ]+\s+[A-ZĐÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸ]+\s+[A-ZĐÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸ]')
matches = re.finditer(regexObj,'''long text source go here''',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
results = [match.group(1) for match in matches]
print (results)

#try to do with collection Counter
words = re.findall("^\w*+\s\w*+\s", file.read())
print (collections.Counter(words))
```

Comment: Do names always appear as `**<name>**`?

Comment: **<name>** is not appear like this. It's my faulty format.

Comment: Here is my Regex attempt, I dont know why it's return only the letter "Y":

Comment: How can you tell a name from a normal word then?

Comment: It's always Title. And a name range from 2 words to 4 words.

Comment: This is all the Caps chacter:
`[A-ZẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ]`

and this is the low:
`[a-zàáảãạăằắẳẵặâầấẩẫậèéẻẽẹêềếểễệìíỉĩịòóỏõọôồốổỗộơờớởỡợùúủũụưừứửữựỳýỷỹỵ]`

Comment: Here is my code, n perfect only 1 problem that's it let out the single A charater in the name "A Lý Khuê Ân", it only find "Lý Khuê Ân".
` [A-ZẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ]([a-zàáảãạăằắẳẵặâầấẩẫậèéẻẽẹêềếểễệìíỉĩịòóỏõọôồốổỗộơờớởỡợùúủũụưừứửữựỳýỷỹỵ]+|\.)(?:\s+[A-ZẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ]([a-zàáảãạăằắẳẵặâầấẩẫậèéẻẽẹêềếểễệìíỉĩịòóỏõọôồốổỗộơờớởỡợùúủũụưừứửữựỳýỷỹỵ]+|\.))\s+[A-ZẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ]([a-zàáảãạăằắẳẵặâầấẩẫậèéẻẽẹêềếểễệìíỉĩịòóỏõọôồốổỗộơờớởỡợùúủũụưừứửữựỳýỷỹỵ]+|\.)`

Comment: Problem of my code is it's only find name with 3 words, cant find name with 2 words or 4. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the more capable 3rd party `regex` module.  `\p{Lu}` represents upper case letters according to the Unicode property of the character.  The `Counter` class can be used for the counting as well:

```
#coding:utf8
import regex
from collections import Counter
s = '''A Lý Khuê Ân tính toán rất rõ ràng. Lúc đầu muốn giết Tát Lạc Mông, hắn không có gì phải sợ. Dù sao Tát Lạc Mông cũng là tốn hao tài phú của Bác Y gia tộc và một nhân tình mới được Ngả Khẳng hỗ trợ. Cho thấy Ngả Khẳng khồng coi trọng. Nếu như Ngả Khảng không lấy tài phú ban cho Tát Lạc Mông một giọt Chủ thần lực, vậy mới gọi là coi trọng. “Giết Tát Lạc Mông không sao, nhưng giết Bối Bối, mặc dù tỷ lệ phát hiện không cao, nhưng bj phát hiện, ta hẳn phải chết không thể nghi ngờ” A Lý Khuê Ân khong hề muốn chọc vào Bối Lỗ Đặc.'''
for k,v in Counter(regex.findall(r'\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s\p{Lu}\w*){1,3}',s)).items():
    #if v > 1:
        print(k,v)
```

Output:

```
A Lý Khuê Ân 2
Ngả Khẳng 2
Bác Y 1
Bối Bối 1
Tát Lạc Mông 3
Ngả Khảng 1
Bối Lỗ Đặc 1
Giết Tát Lạc Mông 1
```

Comment: Sir you are a life saver. Thank you very much. Such a clean and fast method.